# DataMapper (Overzealous edition) and many-to-many with attribute

Tags: codeigniter, datamapper

I'd like to create a relationship with an attribute using datamapper overzealous edition.

I have 2 main models:
 - Role (roles table)
 - Policy (policies table)

a role can have many policies and a policy can have many roles.

To do so I created a relationship table with role_id and policy_id.
I also added to this table an attribute (named permission) that is a boolean value that indicate me if a specific policy in a specific role is allowed or not.

How can I write/update/read this value?

```
$role->policy->get();
```

gives me only all information inside policies table. Instead I'd like to have the informations inside policies table and of the relationship table.

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found the answer yet, but you can access the extra field(s) in a join table through the `get_join_fields()` and `set_join_fields()` methods. You can find more information [in the documentation.](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/joinfields.html)